# Find all integers $n>1$ with the property that for each positive divisor $d$ of $n$, we also have that: $(d+2) \mid(n+2) $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all integers $n>1$ with the property that for each positive divisor $d$ of $n$, we also have that:
$$
(d+2) \mid(n+2)
$$

So far, I've tried to get as much info about it as possible, but I don't know how to proceed.

My attempt so far:
First, we know that $n$ is of the form of the form $3K+1$. Also, if you take the smallest prime divisor of $n$, call it $p$, we know that:

$$
n=pd \Rightarrow d+2 \mid pd+2 \Rightarrow d+2 \mid 2p-2
$$
Hence $p \leq d \leq 2p-4$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If you're writing down your effort, then it'll be better visible if you edit the post and do that rather than do it in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a good start, with this showing how to complete the solution by checking the multiplier. First, with $d = 1$ always being a divisor, we require that $1 + 2 \mid n + 2 \;\to\; n \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \;\to\; n = 3k + 1$, as you've already stated. Since the only other factor of primes is the prime itself, and $d = n$ always satisfies $d + 2 \mid n + 2$, this means that all primes $n$ where

$$n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}\tag{1} \label{eq1A}$$

are solutions. Otherwise, similar to what you did, for any composite $n$, have $p$ be its smallest prime factor. Then $d = \frac{n}{p}$ is also a factor of $n$ so, for some positive integer multiplier $m$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n + 2 & = m\left(\frac{n}{p} + 2\right) \\
n + 2 & = \frac{mn}{p} + 2m \\
pn + 2p & = mn + 2pm \\
(p - m)n & = 2p(m - 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note from the second line above that $m \lt p$ since, otherwise, the RHS is greater than the LHS. Thus, if $p = 2$, then $m \lt 2 \;\to\; m = 1$, but then the last line becomes the incorrect $n = 0$. Otherwise, with $p \gt 2$, then $2 \nmid n$. The last line then shows that $2 \mid p - m$. However, we then get that $n \le p(m - 1) \le p(p - 2)$, but since $n \ge p^2$ (as $n$ is composite and $p$ is the smallest prime factor), this is also not possible.

This proves the only solutions are those given in \eqref{eq1A}, i.e., $n$ which are primes of the form $3k + 1$.